# What kind of LEDs are typically used in lights?

Tags: led

Forgive me if "What kind of LED" is technically incorrect. I'm new to electronics and am trying to build a light (reference link attached below) for making videos. I have some LEDs which come standard in Arduino/RPi kits, but I don't believe they are capable of emitting enough light without burning out. I believe they are 3V/20mA 5mm LEDs.

What kind of LEDs are used in lights such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T8FBZC2)?

Comment: Read the specs. Power consumption is 10W over 66 LEDs. That tells you the power per LED : the voltage is fairly well known (and in the datasheet) giving you a current. Find LEDs whose datasheet says they produce that colour and can handle that current.

Answer (score 0):

Most LEDs used for lighting are small surface-mount devices.  They are soldered direct to a circuit board, which helps take the heat away.  They are also a lot more compact.

You can even buy LED modules, with an array of LEDs already mounted on a circuit board and heatsink.